# Google map doesnt zoom in

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following function which takes the zoom level.
However when I call the setCenter with my positional coords + zoom the map doesn't zoom in where I want to. The position of my info window is correct though. Here is the function:

```
function gotoLocation  (longitude, latitude, zoom, isDefault) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            window.refPointMarker.setPosition(position);
            var info;
            if (isDefault == true) {
                info = "<p style='font-weight:bold; font-size:12;'>Default reference point.</p>";
                info += "<p style='font-size:12;'> Click on the map to select a new location. </p>";
            }
            else {
                info = "<p style='font-weight:bold; font-size:12;'>Current reference point.</p>";
                info += "<p style='font-size:12;'> Click on the map to select a new location. </p>";
            }

            if (window.infoWindow) window.infoWindow.close();
            window.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: info,
                position: position,
                anchor: window.refPointMarker
            });

            window.map.setCenter(position, zoom);
        }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here please?

Comment: Which version of the API are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setZoom function to set your zoom instead of setCenter.

```
var foo = 5;
window.map.setZoom(foo);
```